# How to prevent a website from redirecting to other websites?

Tags: google-chrome, security, redirection, microsoft-edge

One forum I frequent is running ads that sometimes redirects the users to questionable websites. The ads inject a script that uses `window.location.href` to change the URL of the current page.

I've configured the browser to block pop-ups and redirects, but this does not make a difference. uBlock Origin doesn't seem to work either. This affects both Chrome and Microsoft Edge. Anyone know how I can prevent these redirects?

Comment: Adblockers are just tools. Filter lists is how you utilize them. You can create your own filters. Maybe give it a try!